# Does glib have a specific library that needs to be included?

Tags: c, linux, glib, bluez

I am attempting to compile some very simple code that uses the `glib` library. I am getting `undefined reference` compiler errors to my glib functions.

Is there a `glib` library I am supposed to include? I'm not finding much references on the internet.

Below is the simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <glib/garray.h>
#include <glib/gtypes.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    GArray* test = g_array_new(1, 1, 5); // undefined reference to g_array_new

    g_array_free(test, 1);  // undefined reference to g_array_free
    return 0;
}
```

I am currently including the libraries: `-ldbus-1 -lbluetooth -lncurses`. And including the directories: `-I/usr/include/glib-2.0/ -I../../../bluez-5.39 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include`.

Comment: Did you try `-lglib` or `-lglib-2.0`?

Comment: I see you are linking against `ncurses`, `bluetooth` and `dbus` but not `glib`, you should also link against that one.

Comment: Why are you not using pkgconfig to find all requirements?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams whats the glib package name? I tried searching for it.

Comment: It will be somewhere under `/usr/lib{,64}/pkgconfig/`.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to include `-lglib-2.0`

Comment: May be pkg-config is friendly `pkg-config --libs --cflags glib-2.0 gio-2.0`